# Incorrect HTML formatting when sending email from PowerShell to Lotus Notes user

Tags: exchange-server, lotus-notes

I am trying to send a report from Exchange Management Shell Exchange 2007. When I send this report to Outlook the email is formatting as expected, but when I send the email to Lotus it's losing the HTML formatting such as CSS, headings, tables and borders. The data is preserved but the formatting is incorrect.

On the other hand, when I send the message using Send-MailMessage in Exchange 2010 everything is fine even when I send it to a Lotus Notes user.

Why does this difference occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to go to the Notes client, and view the MIME source of both messages and compare them using a good diff program.  If one is displaying correctly, and the other is not, there will be differences, and finding out why and those differences occur should give you some clue about what is happening to break the message.

(The above is assuming that the recipient is set up to receive the message in his mailbox in MIME format.  If, in fact, the user has been set up to receive messages converted to Notes rich text format, then you would have to go to the Domino server instead of the Notes client, and use the [SMTPSaveImportErors](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21095102) setting to capture the MIME source for the two messages.)